# Need an ANT task to include a set of jar files in the final jar's /lib dir

Tags: java, ant, jar

My project folder has a bunch of dependent jars in:

```
/lib/someapi-1.1.1/main.jar
/lib/someotherapi-2.2.2/api-2.2.2.jar
/lib/...
```

I build a JAR file and my application requires that the dependent jars get included in the final jar in the /lib folder within the jar, so the final jar should have a structure something like:

```
/org/me/myclasses.class
/lib/main.jar
/lib/api-2.2.2.jar
```

How do I get the /lib/*.jar files flattened an included in the /lib directory of my final jar file?

---

**CLARIFICATION**

I'm essentially just trying to get a set of resource files flattened and added to a given directory in my final jar.

Comment: I don't really need the executable features and custom classloader of one-jar, I'm using Hadoop here and that application already handles unpacking the /lib directory of the jar file and adding them to its own classpath. I just need to zip the files into /lib, I can do it manually, but I want to automate it.

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to get the files I want flattened and added to a specified path within my jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I see is to copy allyour jars to a temporary folder using the `copy` task and its `flatten` attribute, and to include the jars of this temporary directory into the destination jar.

---

**ADDED DETAIL added by asker**

Here's what the final ANT target looks like (for future reference):

```
  <target name="dist">
    <mkdir dir="${classes}/lib"/>
    <copy flatten="true" todir="${classes}/lib" includeemptydirs="false">
        <fileset dir="lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <jar destfile="${dist}/MyOneBigJar.jar">
        <fileset dir="${classes}"/>
    </jar>
  </target>
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you wanted do skip the copy step, you could do it this way.  It uses [`<mappedresources>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#mappedresources) to flatten from the source lib directories to the classes/lib area.

```
<jar destfile="${dist}/MyOneBigJar.jar">
    <fileset dir="${classes}"/>
    <mappedresources>
      <fileset dir="lib">
          <include name="**/*.jar" />
      </fileset>
      <chainedmapper>
          <flattenmapper />
          <globmapper from="*" to="classes/lib/*" />
      </chainedmapper>
    </mappedresources>
</jar>
```